# Jquery selecting images

Tags: jquery

How do I select images from following HTML document into one variable?

```
<body>
  <h1>First gallery</h1>
  <div class="gallery" title="City Gallery">
    <img src="a.jpg" />
      <p data-target="a.jpg">
        Description for a.
      </p>
    <img src="b.jpg" />
      <p data-target="b.jpg">
        Description for b.
      </p>
...
```

Comment: Please be clear on what you are asking, also share the code for what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".gallery img");
```

This will return an array of your image elements, you can assign it to a variable and loop through it after.

Comment: thanks, but I also need to select only images where gallery has specified title, as there are more galleries

Comment: $(".gallery[title] img") to select a gallery with any title, $(".gallery[title=some title] img") to select one with a specific title

Comment: I get Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .gallery[title=City Gallery] img  jquery.js:1580:8